# What does Revelation 21:5 mean by "everything"?

Tags: exegesis, revelation

Revelation 21:5 (NIV)::

> He who was seated on the throne said, “I am making everything new!” Then he said, “Write this down, for these words are trustworthy and true.”

My pastor included this verse in his sermon today, and after reading it, he added his own emphasis, "And this means **ev-ery-thing!**"

But does it really?

What "everything" is being made new?  My car won't be new again, will it?

**What is this verse *really* saying?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yikes!  This is the danger of taking verses out of context!

---

If we look at Revelations 21:5 in context, this is what we see:

> [Revelations 21:1-5 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelations%2021&version=NIV)
>   Then I saw “a new heaven and a new earth,” for the first heaven and the first earth had passed away, and there was no longer any sea. 2 I saw the Holy City, the new Jerusalem, coming down out of heaven from God, prepared as a bride beautifully dressed for her husband. 3 And I heard a loud voice from the throne saying, “Look! God’s dwelling place is now among the people, and he will dwell with them. They will be his people, and God himself will be with them and be their God. 4 ‘He will wipe every tear from their eyes. There will be no more death’ or mourning or crying or pain, for the old order of things has passed away.”
>
> 5 He who was seated on the throne said, “I am making everything new!” Then he said, “Write this down, for these words are trustworthy and true.”

What God has done in this passage is to *destroy* the old and create things new.  There will be a *new* heaven and a *new* earth.  Will there be new cars?  Probably not.  Will there be new pornography?  Definitely not.  Will there be new guns?  Again, probably not.

> for the old order of things has passed away.

This "New Heaven and a New Earth" cannot be taken as *exactly* like the old heaven and old earth.  The reason is (as listed in Revelations 21:1 above), the old heaven and old earth has passed away.

God has taken away the sins of the world.  He has given us a new earth: a place without sin, without death and decay;  a place like the original Garden of Eden.  We can be pretty sure that not **everything** will be made new.

> [Revelations 21:7-8 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelations%2021:7-8&version=NIV)
>   Those who are victorious will inherit all this, and I will be their God and they will be my children. But the cowardly, the unbelieving, the vile, the murderers, the sexually immoral, those who practice magic arts, the idolaters and all liars—they will be consigned to the fiery lake of burning sulfur. This is the second death.

Comment: +1 for "Will there be new pornography?"  I should ask this one to my Pastor, and see if I can make him blush :)

Answer (score 8):

According to the book of Genesis God created the heavens and the earth. God gave form to the universe. God filled the earth with living beings. God created light. God created us.

Scripture doesn't state that He will duplicate his children's toys.

**That which *God* has created, He will create anew** (including us).

In Revelation 21 it continues with a thorough description of the new Jerusalem. In verses 22-23 it describes;
22)No temple could be seen in the city, for the Lord God Almighty and the Lamb are its temple. 23)And the city has no need of sun or moon, for the glory of God illuminates the city, and the Lamb is its light.

(Doesn't sound like headlights will be necessary.)